# is there any volume shadow copy SDK for windows 8?

Tags: c++, shadow-copy

i tried to install windows volume shadow copy SDK 
but when i see this link it only support for windows 2003 and xp
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23490

i tried to force install to see what will happen and  i developed it with msvc 2010 it gives me errors , whenever i put

```
#include "vswriter.h"
```

it gives me ton of errors

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(117): error 

C2504: 'IUnknown' : base class undefined
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GetPath'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OUT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120): error C2091: function returns function
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120): warning C4183: 'STDMETHOD': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(123): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GetFilespec'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(123): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OUT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(123): error C2091: function returns function
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(123): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(123): error C2535: 'int (__cdecl *IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD(void))(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120) : see declaration of 'IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(123): warning C4183: 'STDMETHOD': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(126): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GetRecursive'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(126): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OUT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(126): error C2091: function returns function
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(126): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(126): error C2535: 'int (__cdecl *IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD(void))(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120) : see declaration of 'IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(126): warning C4183: 'STDMETHOD': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(129): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GetAlternateLocation'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(129): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OUT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(129): error C2091: function returns function
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(129): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(129): error C2535: 'int (__cdecl *IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD(void))(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120) : see declaration of 'IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(129): warning C4183: 'STDMETHOD': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(120): error C2253: 'IVssWMFiledesc::STDMETHOD' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(135): error C2504: 'IUnknown' : base class undefined
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(138): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GetLogicalPath'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft\vsssdk72\inc\winxp\vswriter.h(138): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OUT'
1>c:\pr
```

is that mean vshadow SDK are not supported for win8? or is it discontinued? or am i wrong to install it?

Comment: `IUnknown` errors means you're missing the base COM headers before you `#include` this file. With the Win32 API, it should be [in the base SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968832(v=vs.85).aspx), so if you've got a newer SDK, then you should not need to download this package

Comment: where can i get newer SDK? you mean windows SDK? or API environment in microsoft visual studio for C++?

Comment: Yes, the Windows Win32 SDK. Download it from the [Download Microsoft Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) link, which was on the page that I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Can you try to load this VS2012 solution and see if it builds? If it does, then the project settings/correct order of #includes from this sample can help you.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VSS-Sample-Provider-3096be2a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows SDK for 8/8.1 includes VSS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx

The corresponding 'vshadow' code sample that compiles with this SDK is at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx
*(You don't need to separately install the VSS SDK)*

AFAIK, you cannot compile ATL/COM project with an express edition of Visual Studio (which is also mentioned on the samples page):

> Warning  This sample requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and will not compile in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows.

You would need a Professional/Enterprise version of Visual Studio 2013 or later.